# When set of projections is closed under multiplication

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal A\subset B(H)$ be an unital $C^*$ algebra of operators on a Hilbert space $H$. Let's denote by $\mathcal P$ the set of projections in $\mathcal A$, that is $\mathcal P:=\{a\in \mathcal A \; | \; a=a^2=a^*\}$.

I'm wondering when $\mathcal P$ is closed under composition of operators. I was able to prove the following:

$\big(\mathcal P \text{ is closed under multplication}\big)\Leftrightarrow \big(\forall_{a,b\in \mathcal P}\; ab=ba\big)$

If $\mathcal A$ is a von Neumann algebra then projections spans set which is dense in $\mathcal A$ so in this case $\big(\mathcal P \text{ is closed under multiplication}\big)\Leftrightarrow \big(\mathcal A \text{ is abelian}\big)$. Can something similar be proven in general(without assuming $\mathcal A$ being a von Neumann algebra)?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $\mathcal A=C_r(\mathbb F_2)$ (or any other projectionless unital C$^*$-algebra), then $$\mathcal P=\{0,I\}$$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: Thank You for Your comment, Martin Argerami.
So, there are noncommutative $C^*$  algebras where $\mathcal P$ is closed under multiplication. Is there any useful characterisation of this property?

Comment: I have no answer for that, but I doubt so. It just happens that for some C $^*$-algebras projections are irrelevant. On the other hand many (most?) C $^*$-algebras contain copies of the matrix algebras,  so $\mathcal P $ is not multiplicative.

Comment: Am I right that in this case center of $\mathcal A$ is non trivial? Does something change if we assume triviality of a center?

Comment: The center of $C_r (\mathbb F_2) $ is trivial.

Comment: I might have not stated clearly what I meant. If we assume that the center is trivial, can we say something more about the question whether $\mathcal P$ is multiplicative?

Comment: I don't think so. You have $C_r(\mathbb F_2)$, with trivial $\mathcal P$ (and thus irrelevantly multiplicative), and you have $UHF(2^\infty)$, where $\mathcal P$ spans a dense subset and is (very) non-multiplicative.